How to use hook `element.init` for re-init datepicker with wire:navigate
I create a dynamic adding element form textfield input with livewire 3. Inside this form I have a datepicker field and want to re-init every datepicker field when new element added on that form.
Everythings OK, but when I use wire:navigate to pages navigate, I found an issue. My hook element.init always error when I access this page from another page. When first navigate page visit it ok, but senconds visit error show
Uncaught TypeError: window.Livewire.find(...) is undefined

My view code
@push('script')
    @script
        <script>
            function goBack(e) {
                window.history.back();
            }

            Livewire.hook('element.init', ({ component, el }) => {
                console.log("element.init");
                if (document.querySelectorAll('[id^="date_"]').length) {
                    initializeDatepickers();
                }
            });

            function initializeDatepickers() {
                // Check if rows exist in the Livewire component
                const rows = @this.get('rows');
                if (!rows || !Array.isArray(rows)) {
                    return;
                }

                // Iterate through each row and initialize datepicker
                rows.forEach((row, index) => {
                    const datepickerId = `#date_${index}`;
                    const $datepickerElement = $(datepickerId);

                    // Ensure the datepicker element exists before initializing
                    if ($datepickerElement.length) {
                        // Destroy existing datepicker to avoid conflicts
                        if ($datepickerElement.data('datepicker')) {
                            $datepickerElement.datepicker('destroy');
                        }
                        $datepickerElement.datepicker({
                            todayHighlight: true,
                            orientation: "bottom left",
                            autoclose: true,
                            format: "dd-mm-yyyy"
                        }).on("changeDate", function (e) {
                            @this.set(`rows.${index}.date`, e.format());
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

            $('#tanggal_ajuan').datepicker({
                todayHighlight: true,
                orientation: "bottom left",
                autoclose: true,
                format: "dd-mm-yyyy"
            }).on("changeDate", function (e) {
                @this.set('tanggal_ajuan', e.format());
            });
        </script>
    @endscript
@endpush

Now I decide to not use wire:navigate but how to fix this issue? But I still prefer to use wire:navigate. How to fix this issue?
